# Defining a type parameter on subtypes of the current class

Tags: scala

I'm playing with Scala's implicit parameters and, while I might be trying to go take it a bit too far, have encountered something that I just cannot seem to work out.

The example I'm working on is fairly simple: a process yields results which are all instances of the same base class, but can sometimes be specialised. These results need to be serialised to a variety of formats (say, JSON and XML for, for example), which seems like the perfect use case for type classes:

```
// All results are instances of Result.
trait Result {
  def value: String
  def count: Int
}

// Implementations are used to format results to any format that can be implemented.
trait ResultFormatter[T <: Result, B] {
  def format(t: T): B
}

// One type of result.
case class ResultA(value: String, count: Int) extends Result

// Another type of result.
case class ResultB(value: String, count: Int, details: String) extends Result


object ResultFormatter {
  // Formats a result to the appropriate type if an implicit formatter is in scope.
  def format[T <: Result, B](t: T)(implicit format: ResultFormatter[T, B]): B = format.format(t)

  // Formats instances of ResultA to strings.
  implicit val StringA = new ResultFormatter[ResultA, String] {
    override def format(a: ResultA): String = "%s (%d)" format (a.value, a.count)
  }

  // Formats instances of ResultB to strings.
  implicit val StringB = new ResultFormatter[ResultB, String] {
    override def format(b: ResultB): String = "%s (%d) [%s]" format (b.value, b.count, b.details)
  }
}

// Through the magic of implicit parameters and type classes, instances of ResultA and ResultB are formatted
// to the appropriate type without having to modify either.
println(ResultFormatter.format(ResultA("result A", 1)))
println(ResultFormatter.format(ResultB("result B", 2, "foo bar")))
```

What I'd really like to do, however, is have `format` be a member of `Result` and allow calls such as, for example, `result.format[JObject]`.

```
trait Result {
  def value: String
  def count: Int
  def format[T <: Result, B](implicit format: ResultFormatter[T, B]): B = format.format(this)
}
```

But this isn't legal, as `this` is an instance of `Result`, not an instance of `T`.

Is there a way to do this, or must I either drop the idea or change my model, such as it is, to achieve a similar functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
trait Result {
  def value: String
  def count: Int
  def format[B](implicit f: ResultFormatter[this.type , B]): B = f.format(this)
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you change your previous answer (`this.type`)? It worked fine, better in fact than this new answer, provided I changed the variance of `ResultFormatter`.

Comment: Did it work? Hmm. For me compilation failed with error: ```could not find implicit value for parameter f: x.ResultFormatter[_1.type,String]```

Comment: I had that too, but that was because `ResultFormatter` needed to be contravariant on `T` (I still need to play with this a bit to make sure I understand why). If you roll your edit back, I'd be happy to accept your answer.

Comment: Ha. True collaboration. Thanks